# Limit number files in jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I use plugin  jQuery-File-Upload.
How can I to limit of number selecting files from local machine?

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the number of files before submitting by adding a onchange event to the input element. As soon as it's triggered you check the number of files. Here is a simple example for a 2 file limit:

```
<input type="file" onchange="if(parseInt($(this).get(0).files.length)>2) 
                               alert('You can only upload a maximum of 2 files'); 
                             else alert('You are within the limit');" multiple/>
```

[See demo on fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FordPerfect/uw0ufcmj/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxNumberOfFiles`

```
$('#file-upload').fileupload({

maxNumberOfFiles: 6

});
```

Found in the documentation: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#maxnumberoffiles

Comment: You are looking to limit the number of files to be selected, before submitting. right. I believe this limits the number of submitted files.